# STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER from NtCreateFile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Here is the code I am using:

```
std::wstring GetPathFromFileReference (DWORDLONG frn)
{
    if (frn != 0)
    {
        HANDLE handle = NULL;

        wchar_t file_buffer[2048] = { NULL };
        wchar_t unicode_buffer[8] = { NULL };
        UNICODE_STRING unicodeString;

        unicodeString.Length = 8;
        unicodeString.MaximumLength = 8;
        unicodeString.Buffer = unicode_buffer;

        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttributes = { NULL };
        InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttributes, &unicodeString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, _root, NULL); 

        IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock = { NULL };

        LARGE_INTEGER allocSize = { NULL };
        int _result = NtCreateFile(&handle, GENERIC_ALL /*FILE_TRAVERSE*/ /* FILE_READ_DATA */, &objAttributes, &ioStatusBlock, /*&allocSize*/  NULL , NULL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID | FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE /*FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT*/, NULL, NULL);
        if (_result == S_OK)
        {
            typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *LPFN_NtQueryInformationFile) (HANDLE, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK, PVOID, ULONG, int);
            LPFN_NtQueryInformationFile pfnNtQueryInformationFile = (LPFN_NtQueryInformationFile)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationFile");

            _result = pfnNtQueryInformationFile(handle, &ioStatusBlock, file_buffer, 4096, 9);
            if (_result == S_OK)
            {
                return std::wstring(file_buffer + 2);
            }
        }
    }
    return L"";
}
```

The call to `NtCreateFile` is failing with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The commented out bits of code in that call show other things I have tried.

The RootDirectory handle is definitely getting set in objAttributes (to 0x30). I am using this same handle elsewhere in the code, and it is working perfectly. And the frn looks good too.

I have no idea what else to try or how to narrow the cause down any further :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention what I am trying to achieve here. Sorry! The frn comes from the USN Change Journal. I have successfully read the Change Journal using my root handle (hence I believe it is correct), and for each entry I have got an frn and parent_frn. I want to get the full path to the file, and the code below is how I am trying to convert frn to path. Both frn and parent_frn give the same `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` return code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment on the documentation for [NtCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that:

> If using FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID, the ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory handle MUST be filled in with a handle to the volume, otherwise you will get STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.

To open a handle to a volume you can use `CreateFile` using a path of `\\.\X:` where X is the drive letter.  Note there is no trailing backslash.  The [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation has info about it (look for the string "Opens the C: volume.")

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have already done this (generated the handle in exactly the way you have suggested). I am also using this same handle to read from the Change Journal (so I know the handle is good), and I can confirm using the debugger that the handle is getting copied into ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory fine. Any other ideas? :p This is really doing my head in. Your help is greatly appreciated, but I am not yet convinced this is the answer. Thanks again, though.

Comment: My only other thought is that you're not using [RtlInitUnicodeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561934.aspx) to initialize the unicode string.  It also looks like objAttributes.ObjectName is an 8 byte buffer with zeroes in it.  I'm not sure that will relate to a valid File ID?

Comment: Thank you!! I haven't quite solved my problem yet, but I am making headway with your help. Firstly, I was being completely stupid with the UNICODE_STRING. I set it to point to an 16 byte buffer, but never actually filled the buffer! So NtCreateFile was never actually getting sent the FileID. But as you say, the problem runs deeper than just this. Please give me some time to take a look. I might be able to solve this by myself, before asking for your time again. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem.  According to the docs the buffer should by 8 bytes long though!

Comment: Yes...it is a bit of a pain actually. Reading around, what I have to do is take my DWORDLONG value, truncate it down to 64bits long (the ID should always be short enough for this to safely happen...in theory at least), and then copy this binary into the UNICODE_STRING buffer.

Comment: Oh...only just realised DWORDLONG is guaranteed to be 64bits long: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230321.aspx. That makes things easier.

Comment: STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY I love you! I think it is a sign of progress :p

Comment: Oh, thank you, thank you! My code now works! It was as simple as UNICODE_STRING unicodeString; unicodeString.Length = 8; unicodeString.MaximumLength = 8; unicodeString.Buffer = (wchar_t*)&frn; THANK YOU!!!